# MySQL get multiple result from one table in one row

Tags: mysql

The are two tables "costs" and "contacts". Names off all sellers and buyers are in "contacts" table. With following query i retrieve the id of seller and buyer for each item but I want to get their names from "contacts" table

```
SELECT 
costs.id as ID,
costs.idContactPayedBy,
costs.idContactPayedTo

FROM costs

WHERE 
costs.idbuilding=286
```

but I want to get seller and buyers names from contacts table

```
SELECT 
costs.id as ID,
contacts.lastname as seller,
contacts.lastname as buyer

FROM costs , contacts

WHERE 
costs.idbuilding=286
and costs.idContactPayedBy = contacts.id
and costs.idContactPayedTo = contacts.id
```

so the desired result is like this

```
ID  Seller   Buyer
21  jackson  Brown
29  Bush     wilson
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
c.id as ID,
cntby.lastname as seller,
cntto.lastname as buyer

FROM costs AS c 
INNER JOIN contacts AS cntby ON c.idContactPayedBy = cntby.id
INNER JOIN contacts AS cntto ON c.idContactPayedTo = cntto.id
WHERE c.idbuilding=286
```

Note 1: Use `INNER JOIN` only if `idContactPayed[By/To]` columns are mandatory (`NOT NULL`). If these columns allows nulls then you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. In my opinion, both columns should be mandatory.

Note 2: As a matter of style: please avoid [old style joins (ANSI 86/89)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins): `FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE <join condition>`.